# Loop ansible_host stuck with first item

Tags: loops, ansible

I am using the module csv-source-of-truth (https://github.com/joelwking/csv-source-of-truth) to get the IP and OS information from a csv file. I was able to register these info into a vsheet and using debug, I can see that I can loop through the contents of the vsheet.

However, when I use ios_command and try to loop through the vsheet, it seems that it gets stuck at the first entry of the vsheet.

This are the contents of the Inventory.csv file:

192.168.68.201,ios

192.168.68.202,ios

Code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Block
      block:
          - name: Use CSV

            csv_to_facts:
              src: '{{playbook_dir}}/NEW/Inventory.csv'
              vsheets:
                - INFO:
                    - IP
                    - OS

          - debug:
              msg: '{{item.IP}}'
            loop: '{{INFO}}'

          - name: Show Version
            vars:
              ansible_host: '{{item.IP}}'
              ansible_network_os: '{{item.OS}}'
              ansible_user: cisco
              ansible_ssh_pass: cisco
              ansible_connection: network_cli
              ansible_become: yes
              ansible_become_method: enable
            ios_command:
              commands: show version
            register: output
            loop: '{{INFO}}'

          - name: Show the output of looped Show Version
            debug:
              var: output

          - name: Show just the stdout_lines
            debug:
              var: output.results.{{item}}.stdout_lines
            with_sequence: "0-{{output|length - 2}}"
```

You will notice on the output that it only has results for R1 when you look at the uptime information. i.e. R1 has an uptime of such and such.

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Use CSV] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'IP': u'192.168.68.201', u'OS': u'ios'}) => {
    "msg": "192.168.68.201"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'IP': u'192.168.68.202', u'OS': u'ios'}) => {
    "msg": "192.168.68.202"
}

TASK [Show Version] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'IP': u'192.168.68.201', u'OS': u'ios'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'IP': u'192.168.68.202', u'OS': u'ios'})

TASK [Show the output of looped Show Version] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "auth_pass": null,
                        "authorize": null,
                        "commands": [
                            "show version"
                        ],
                        "host": null,
                        "interval": 1,
                        "match": "all",
                        "password": null,
                        "port": null,
                        "provider": null,
                        "retries": 10,
                        "ssh_keyfile": null,
                        "timeout": null,
                        "username": null,
                        "wait_for": null
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "IP": "192.168.68.201",
                    "OS": "ios"
                },
                "stdout": [
                   -- Output removed for brevity
                ],
                "stdout_lines": [
                    [
                        "-- Output removed for brevity

                        "R1 uptime is 1 hour, 34 minutes",

                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "auth_pass": null,
                        "authorize": null,
                        "commands": [
                            "show version"
                        ],
                        "host": null,
                        "interval": 1,
                        "match": "all",
                        "password": null,
                        "port": null,
                        "provider": null,
                        "retries": 10,
                        "ssh_keyfile": null,
                        "timeout": null,
                        "username": null,
                        "wait_for": null
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "IP": "192.168.68.202",
                    "OS": "ios"
                },
                "stdout": [
                   -- Output removed for brevity
                ],
                "stdout_lines": [
                    [
                       -- Output removed for brevity
                        "R1 uptime is 1 hour, 34 minutes",

                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Show just the stdout_lines] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "0",
    "output.results.0.stdout_lines": [
        [
           -- Output removed for brevity
            "R1 uptime is 1 hour, 34 minutes",

        ]
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "1",
    "output.results.1.stdout_lines": [
        [
           -- Output removed for brevity
            "R1 uptime is 1 hour, 34 minutes",
        ]
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hint: have a look at [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html), create a dynamic group from your hosts in your CSV and target that group in a subsequent play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create an inventory

```
      - name: Create inventory
        add_host:
          hostname: '{{ item.IP }}'
          groups: temp_group_01
          ansible_network_os: '{{ item.OS }}'
          ansible_user: cisco
          ansible_ssh_pass: cisco
          ansible_connection: network_cli
          ansible_become: yes
          ansible_become_method: enable
        loop: '{{ INFO }}'
```

and delegate to the hosts

```
      - name: Show Version
        ios_command:
          commands: show version
        register: output
        delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
        loop: '{{ groups['temp_group_01'] }}'
```

**Explanation**

From the play below can be seen that the connection does not obey the changed *ansible_host* and keeps using the first item in the loop.

```
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - command: hostname
      register: result
      vars:
        ansible_host: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - test_02
        - test_03
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"
```

gives

```
TASK [command] ******************************************************************************
changed: [test_01] => (item=test_02)
changed: [test_01] => (item=test_03)

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": [
        "test_02", 
        "test_02"
    ]
}
```

This behavior is very probably caused by the connection plugin because *vars* works as expected. The play below

```
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - command: echo "{{ ansible_host }}"
      register: result
      vars:
        ansible_host: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - test_02
        - test_03
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"
```

gives

```
TASK [command] ******************************************************************************
changed: [test_01] => (item=test_02)
changed: [test_01] => (item=test_03)

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": [
        "test_02", 
        "test_03"
    ]
}
```

As a result, it's not possible to loop *ansible_host*. Instead, *delegate_to* shall be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked, it looped through the other rows. Can you please explain to me how did that work?

Comment: You're welcome! I've added the explanation section to the answer.